# Formatting time in swift (iOS)

Tags: swift

I'm formatting the time in a line with the following code

```
let secondsFromGMT = 0
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: secondsFromGMT)
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

The output will be as follows

```
2018-09-28T10:27:05Z
```

I would like that the format would not differ from the version when the timezone is more than 1 minute (say)

```
2018-09-28T10:30:19+00:01
```

That is, I want the format is not abbreviated. Is it possible to do this without changing the manual?

p.s. Tested the function TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT () on the simulator in iOS 10.3.1, the value is 0, and in iOS 12.0 is 10800. Is this a simulator problem?

Comment: Use `xxx` instead of `ZZZZZ`. Check this: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table (bottom of the table)

Comment: @Larme thx you very match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larme gave the right answer, so the solution is:

```
let secondsFromGMT = 0
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: secondsFromGMT)
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

The output will be as follows

```
2018-09-28T10:30:19+00:00
```